# Помогите разобраться с Promise

Tags: javascript

Создать класс, который производит экземпляр со следующими свойствами:
- promise - промис, который создается во время запуска конструктора;
- reject - метод, при выполнении которого promise реджектится;
- resolve - метод, при выполнении которого promise резолвится.

```
class Prom {...}
const inst = new Prom();
inst.promise.then(data => console.log(data));
inst.resolve('test'); 
→  test
```

я делаю такой код, но не могу понять логику выполнения.

```
class Prom {
    constructor () {
        this.promise = new Promise ((res,rej)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                res('text')
            },100)
        })
    }
    resolve(value){
        return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                res(value)
            })
        })
    }
}
const inst = new Prom();
inst.promise.then((data)=> console.log(data));
inst.resolve('text');
```

Comment: А что именно не ясно? Конкретизируйте.

Comment: не понятна суть реализации. в часности как инициализировать Промис в конструкторе, и как написать отдельно методы resolve() reject()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конструктор [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Parameters) передается функция, которая принимает 2 параметра. Один из параметров переводит Promise в статус resolve. Второй - в статус reject.

Поэтому для решения всей задачи достаточно сохранить эти методы в поля класса и вызвать их в нужных методах:

```js
class Prom {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      this.res = res;
      this.rej = rej;
    })
  }
  resolve(value) {
    this.res(value);
  }
  reject(reason) {
    this.rej(reason);
  }
}
const inst = new Prom();
inst.promise.then((data) => console.log(data));
inst.resolve('text');

const inst2 = new Prom();
inst2.promise.then((data) => console.log(data), (reason) => console.log(`rejected with reason: ${reason}`));
inst2.reject('manual');
```

Comment: Большое спасибо